# Get the Destination address from the ICMP header of a ping response

Tags: linux, ping, icmp

I want to perform a ping request or other fake request and print the whole response from the command line. Practically I'd like to see the same information I can see with Wireshark so that I can retrieve the Destination address from the response.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: So you're looking for your own local IP address used for the ping? no need to send a packet for this, you can ask the kernel: `ip route get 10.0.19.21` will display `src 10.40.192.116` its it routing informations.

Comment: Yes right, that solution I'm currently using but I would like to understand why there isn't any tool able to return the ICMP response header, it's like that information is lost in some low-level libraries

Comment: I don't know if this info interests you, but anyway. On Linux for datagram oriented sockets (so udp and probably icmp/raw socket), you can use IP_PKTINFO (man ip.7) to retrieve the information about the incoming destination address. A good UDP daemon working in unconnected mode and not binding to a specific IP address should always do this, to avoid choosing the wrong source IP to reply to a query on a multi-homed system. Other *nix have similar options for the same goal (eg: IP_ORIGDSTADDR/IP_RECVORIGDSTADDR on FreeBSD. It's available on linux too but the former is more generic).